# Freeradius Proxy eap-mschapv2 auth to non-eap Radius server

Tags: radius, freeradius, strongswan, eap

I'm using strongswan 5.6.0 & Freeradius 3.0.13 on CentOS7 as vpn server
- Strongswan send radius requests to freeradius
- freeradius proxy all request to another Radius Server that not support EAP challenge

All non-eap request from freeradius proxy successfully accepted by Radius Server(non-eap), but all eap requests goes fail !

I think requests from Strongswan are eap-mschapv2 (IKEv2 Connections)

How Can I proxy eap requests to non-eap Radius Server
technically I dont know what it should to be, but I think there is 3 idea:
1- Freeradius process all eap itself and just ask the plain-text user/pass from non-eap Radius Server
2- Freeradius convert the eap-mschapv2 to mschapv2 (non-eap) and then send it to non-eap Radius Server
3- Strongswan do the convert or palin-text job

I read a lot of questions and tutorial, but non of them works
help me please
thanks

Comment: nothing ??!   realy ?!?